# How to prove that F: I -> J does not exist.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I've been struggling to wrap up my mind around this problem.
How to prove that continous function, which is also surjection, with 2020 zeros of a function can't be contructed as following: I = [a;b) and J = (c;d), F: I -> J.
There is no need of a full answer, just need a hint on what theorem to use to make it easier to prove that is not possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: apparently the idea is it will be impossible to map $a$ in a continuous way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if the number of zeros is finite, there are no zeros in the interval $(c, b)$, where $c$ is the maximum of the zeros, and
your function is either always positive there or always negative there.  If it's always positive, the function must attain its minimum...